# echo text from input

Tags: javascript, code-generation

I am trying to make a basic border radius generator. I have an input field for the user to type in the number of their choice as shown below:

```
<label>Border Radius:</label>
<input name="border-radius" class="jj_input" type="text" size="2" />
```

I then have an output area where I want the number they have typed in to appear before "px"

```
<div class="yourcode">
     border-radius: *NUMBER_APPEARS_HERE*px;
</div>
```

Im not sure how to go about this, so could someone please point me in the right direction. Please also let me know if this has been answered already. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working in the end:

```
<label>Border Radius:</label>
<input name="border-radius" id="jj_input" class="jj_input" type="text" size="2" value='' onkeyup='changeRadius()' />

<div class="yourcode">
    border-radius: <span id="radius"></span>px;
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeRadius(){
        var jj_input = document.getElementById('jj_input').value;
        document.getElementById('radius').innerHTML = jj_input;
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The input element has an onchange (or onkeyup) event that you can use. You can execute javascript inside that event that sets the innertext of your target div.
Onchange fires after validation (mostly this means when the user leaves the box). If you want to change directly after input, and only keyboard input is permitted, you can use a keydown/up event. In the example below onkeyup is used

```
<label>Border Radius:</label>

<input name="border-radius" class="jj_input" type="text" size="2" onkeyup = "document.getElementById('displaydiv').innerText = 'border-radius: '  + this.value + ' px'" />

 <div class="yourcode" id="displaydiv">
 border-radius: ..px;
 </div>
```

A bit more elegant solution uses a separate span for the .. instead of replacing the entire text, but for demonstration purposes the above should suffice.

Comment: got it working in the end. thanks for the contibution and idea.